# Gwt application does not appear in IE7

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-7

I created a gwt application....

It runs under current Chrome, FIlefox,Opera, IE8

but it does not work under IE7 at least on certain machines. 
It means the embedded gwt application is not visible at all.
There is no javascript error. (Checked with Web Visual Studio) The version of IE is 7.0.6001.18000. The javascript is turned on.
It did not work on one machine and it does work on my machine inside IETESTER.

The program does not use ie7 specific code. 
Is it known bug? Is gwt not ok with ie7? 
What may be the reason?

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using? Also, do you have any error message to show?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have not set your user.agent property to exclude ie in xxxxx.gwt.xml.
For example `<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko"/>` will only compile javascript for firefox and this application will not run properly on an IE environment when deployed.

Answer (score 2):

I traced the javascripts on the page.
I found there was a bmi.js javascript included in the page.
It failed and caused the gwt application not to appear and not to run.

This script is inserted into the page by Vodaphone mobile connect software to optimise downloading images in webpages. It causes some webpages to run incorrectly, not only gwt applications.
On the IE 7 machine , the internet is used throught mobile internet.
Here is the relevant information: http://forum.vodafone.co.uk/index.php?showtopic=8611

Answer (score 1):

It's not GWT itself - currently working on a GWT app at work that works on IE6+, Firefox2+ etc... The problem is probally related to something else in the code/Gui layout

Answer (score 1):

GWT is compatible with all the IE6, 7 & 8.

It's your code. You need to turn on debugging in IE (from the advanced menu from memory) and look for any javascript errors. It would probably also be helpful to compile your code in PRETTY mode instead of OBF(USCATED) so you can see where the error is.

Comment: It looks like it is getting complicated. I assumed it does not work on all IE7. It did not work on one machine and it works in Ietester.

Comment: what's complicated about turning on IE debugging and looking for javascript errors? If you don't want to do that then it's time to hang up the boots and look for a different job ;)

Comment: There are no javascripts that is what IE7 and debugger showed.